# Rank Two Approximations for a Matrix using SVD

Tags: matrix

I need to find a rank 2 approximation in mathematica with the SVD

```
A = {{0,2,3,4},{2,2,4,5},{3,4,4,6},{4,5,6,6}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps look up SingularValueDecomposition in the help. Observe the second argument.

Comment: Sorry but i still dont understand what i am supposed to do

Comment: Probably best to ask the instructor.

Comment: A small problem is that i need to hand this in tomorrow(I know I am really late)